# Launching Internet Explorer from a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I’ve put together some PS code that does the following inside of a larger PS script:

- Test if an IE process is already running
- If IE is not already running, start a new process, open site one in that process then open site two in the foreground tab of that process
- Make the IE process full screen

  ```
  If (-Not (Get-Process IExplore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
      {
      $navOpenInForegroundTab = 0x10000;
      $ie = New-Object -Com InternetExplorer.Application
      $ie.Visible = $True;
      $ie.Navigate2("https://stackoverflow.com");
      $ie.Navigate2("http://superuser.com", $navOpenInForegroundTab);

  $sw = @'
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int nCmdShow);
  '@

      $type = Add-Type -Name ShowWindow2 -MemberDefinition $sw -Language CSharpVersion3 -Namespace Utils -PassThru
      $type::ShowWindow($ie.hwnd, 3) # 3 = maximize 
      }
  ```

Everything seems to work fine, except that after this code runs, it shows the number *24* in the PowerShell window (I am launching PS from the command line).  Can anyone tell me why *24* is being displayed when I run the above code and is it possible to stop it from being displayed?

Comment: This might be return value from the ShowWindow function. If this is the case you would write `$type::ShowWindow($ie.hwnd, 3) | out-null`.

Comment: Yes, it's from ShowWindow. If it's a non-zero value, then the window was not previously hidden, i.e. it's visible, that's what it means. More about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Excellent - thank you.  That is what was going on and the script now runs B-E-A-UTIFULLY

Comment: @STGdb post it as an answer and accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the return value from the ShowWindow function. To ignore the result, use:

```
$type::ShowWindow($ie.hwnd, 3) | out-null
```