# Powercli issue to launch internet explorer in remote machine

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, powercli, esxi, vmware-workstation

I am trying to launch internet explorer and pass the url in remote machine using a bat file. I am using `powercli` to execute the bat script.

**Problem:** When I tried to launch calculator, it launches successfully but when I tried to launch internet explorer, it runs but in background. So, basically I wanted to launch IE in foreground so, I can see and perform actions.

Using command to execute bat file: 
**Invoke-VMScript -VM 'machine_name' -ScriptType bat -ScriptText 'C:\Users\jeet\Desktop\launchBrowser.bat' -GuestUser user -GuestPassword password**

**Content of bat file which is present in desktop:**
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore

**Note: Command runs successfully without showing any error**

Comment: This is an example using `powershell`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706389/launching-internet-explorer-from-a-powershell-script

Comment: @Jelphy Thanks for sharing but I think the script opens IE in base machine but my requirement is to open IE in remote machine from base machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by schtasks for scheduling ask

```
Invoke-VMScript -vm windows10 -guestUser shibu -guestPassword password -ScriptText 
'schtasks /create /tn task100 /f /tr \"C:/Users/shibu/Desktop/launchBrowser.bat 
file://C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe\" /sc weekly'

Invoke-VMScript -vm windows10 -guestUser shibu -guestPassword password -ScriptText 
'schtasks /run /tn task100'
```